# pip install for whl files

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, python-wheel

I am trying to install scipy package for python 2.7 in windows,
The process i followed is as follows:

1. downloaded a whl file scipy-0.17.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl from
    http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy
2. tried to install by
    pip install scipy-0.17.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl

   error : Requirement 'scipy-0.15.1-cp27-none-win32.whl' looks like
    a filename but the file does not exist
    scipy-0.15.1-cp27-none-win32.whl is not a supported wheelon this platform.
3. then tried to install by 
   pip install file_location\scipy-0.17.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl.

   error displayed :scipy-0.15.1-cp27-none-win32.whl is not a supported wheel          on this platform.

   Also i have already upgraded my pip command.
   Can anyone suggest me out some valid solutions?

Comment: You have a typo in step 2. Can you show cut-and-paste the exact command you use and the error you get back? Are you sure that's the correct platform?

Comment: Hey, i have made changes in the command in step 2.
I am trying to install it in windows platform using the mentioned commands. Why would this create a platform conflict?

Comment: you need file along with path . but you did it. what about python bit? 32 or 64? not about OS asking about your python ..

Answer (score 0):

I Think the issue in Python interpreter variant 32 or 64.. if your python is 32-bit then use `scipy-0.17.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl` otherwise if your python  is 64Bit then try `scipy-0.17.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: hey yes as you said i checked for the python bit which is 64
and downloaded a different file accordingly from 
https://pypi.anaconda.org/carlkl/simple/scipy/ i.e
scipy-0.15.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl   
and used the command : pip install file_location\scipy-0.15.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl  
it worked thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome.. If my answer Helps you accept my answer and give up vote to help others too about this answer . thanks ..